# Fire an ASP.NET TextBox event on enter press

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How do i fire a ASP.NET click event when the user press enter.

This is what i do now but it does not work:

```
function KeyDownHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        __doPostBack('<% ButtonGetListforUser.ClientID %>', 'OnClick');
        isClicked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use the [Panel.DefaultButton Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx)

Comment: This worked for me. Wrap your textbox and button in a Panel control and set the DefaultButton to the id of the button control.

Answer (score 2):

i used this exsample to make it work
[Panel.DefaultButton Property Exsample](http://kpumuk.info/asp-net/using-panel-defaultbutton-property-with-linkbutton-control-in-asp-net/)

Comment: Can you please post some sample code here. I am new to asp.net. (cant understand that link)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(window).keydown(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 13) $('#<% ButtonGetListforUser.ClientID %>'.click();
   }); 
});
```

Comment: give some Explanation please. obviously this is JavaScript but you could mention that you went with a JavaScript approach and why.

Answer (score -3):

**This answer for C# ASPNET**
Control name : **Textbox1**

- **Add TextChanged event** for the textbox then add your code in this block
  as below.

  ```
  protected void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Add your code here
  }
  ```
- **Add below block to add Enter event to textbox**

  ```
  private void Textbox1_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
      Textbox1_TextChanged((object)sender, (EventArgs)e);
  }
  ```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.