# Enter key event for TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, keypress

I am new to asp.net. Here I am trying to create a chat application. In my project there is one label and one TextBox. whenever the user enters anything in TextBox and press `enter` the text will be shown in `Label`.    I tried the below code:

**OnEnterKeyPress** of TextBox (.aspx.cs file)

```
        HttpRequest request = base.Request;           
        Ping p = new Ping();
        PingReply r;
        String s = request.UserHostAddress;  //using own IP address for understanding purpose.
        r = p.Send(s);
        Response.Buffer = false;
        if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        }
```

I dont know how to keep the enter event. (There are no events in TextBox properties as it were in C#)

Before asking here I checked many links like [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158752/fire-event-on-enter-key-press-for-a-asp-net-textbox) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158752/fire-event-on-enter-key-press-for-a-asp-net-textbox) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4254576/1577396) but no use. I could have used simple Javascript but the main code is in C# file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put this in its own form and use javascript, since it will be in a page with other controls. You don't want to "submit" the page every time they type something.

```
<form action="javascript:chat()">
put label and textbox here
</form>
```

This will make "enter" work for the textbox. For the chat feature, to make it more interactive, you can implement with http://signalr.net/

Comment: your explanation is not clear to me. I cant understand how to download signalR. can you please explain it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... my answer addresses your question of how to capture the enter key event for a TextBox. I mentioned SignalR just for something for you to consider when you start trying to make the chat work in real-time. To install SignalR, from your project in Visual Studio, go to Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console. In the console type Install-Package SignalR. If you run into a new problem with your project, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one button in the form that you want to enable 'enter' on, you can set it to be the default

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Form.DefaultButton = myTextBox.UniqueID;
}
```

For any button, you will need to use Javascript. You can still use C# to add the attributes. (from [here](http://yrbyogi.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/text-box-enter-key-in-asp-net/))

```
myTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.which || event.keyCode)
                  {if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) 
                      {document.getElementById('"+Button1.UniqueID+"').click();
                                         return false;}} else {return true};");
```

Comment: It is not the only button in the form. Actually I even dont know how the site is because my work will be integrated in to the main site later.

Comment: This. And if you want this to be interactive, you probably don't want to submit the page every time. Check out SignalR.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev ya I heard SignalR from one of my previous questions before but I have no idea about it. Can you please provide me a sample code on it.. so that I can refer it..

Comment: @Mr_Green - Then you need to add some Javascript. I've updated my post.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - Isn't adding an async framework to handle the enter button a bit overkill? It might be useful for the whole site, but OP seems be working on part of it.

Comment: To handle a button? Indeed. To handle a chat feature for a website? No.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you might be facing here is the event will be processed server side ( after post ). You'll probably still need a javascript to do the post when the enter key has been pressed..

I'm also not certain if the OnEnterKeyPressed is a valid event.